# Assembly x86_64 printing single ASCII character with SYSCALL

Tags: assembly, character, ascii, x86-64, system-calls

Firstly, a bit of context: I have only been doing assembly for a few weeks and i have a VERY rought understanding of it. I'm using Assembly x86_64 with AT&T syntax and the GCC compiler.

All i am currently trying to do is figure out how to print a character if i know its ASCII code. For instance, 48 should be '0'.
Therefore, to achieve this with syscall, I figured that this would work:

```
movq $1, %rax
movq $1, %rdi
movq $48, %rsi
movq $1, %rdx
syscall
```

However, that just gets fully ignored. It does not throw errors, it doesn't get segmentation faults, it just does not do anything.

The code that I am working on is supposed to convert integers to strings, and I believe that it is doing that well, but the printing is just not working for me. It is obvious that I am doing something quite wrong, but I can't seem to find it. Is there another way that I should pass the character code to the syscall?

For reference, here is the full code:

```
main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    movq $0, %r9
    movq $1234, %rdi

    splitting_loop:
        movq $0, %rdx
        movq %rdi, %rax
        movq $10, %rbx
        div %rbx

        addq $48, %rdx
        pushq %rdx
        movq %rax, %rdi

        incq %r9
        cmpq $0, %rdi
        jg splitting_loop

    printing_loop:
        popq %rsi
        movq $1, %rax
        movq $1, %rdi
        movq $1, %rdx
        syscall

        decq %r9
        cmpq $0, %r9
        jg printing_loop

    movq $0, %rdi
    call exit
```

Thank you in advance!
-Vlad

Comment: The write system call expects a pointer. To print a character put it in memory and pass its address. See [man write](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) You should be getting an `-EFAULT` return value though.

Comment: That worked, thank you !